# file picker issue in xamarin forms for Android

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using [xamarin.plugin.FilePicker](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows) to get files from Users in xamarin forms for Android. But it doesn't work propoerly.

When i test in physical Android device and try to get any file like PDF, doc then it crash my app or sometimes it redirect me to my app's home page. When i tap to upload file then debugger stops so i can not debug the issue in physical device. I have added neccessary permission in project to read, write files from storage. i don't need iOS app so i don't test on it.

Code to pick file:

```
FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            if (fileData == null)
                return; // user canceled file picking

            string fileName = fileData.FileName;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            var ext = fi.Extension;
            string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);
            var docBase64Path = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData.DataArray);
            int documentTypeId = 0;
```

Permissions for Android in Android menifest:
[image]

Hope for better solution.

Comment: Have you tried FilePicker in Xamarin Essentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below things under manifest file,

```
<application android:label="AppName" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

in Android, under Resources create folder xml and Add xml file **file_paths** .under that file please Add Below Code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <cache-path name="all_dirs" path="." />
        <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
        <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
        <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
   </paths>
```

Let me know if any other help required.

Answer (score 0):

That package is no longer maintained (the repo has been **archived**) it has been moved to [FilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker) in [Xamarin.Essential](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) package which is officially maintained by Microsoft.

Look at that repo github page there is a [Migration Guide](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows#migration-guide)